Асинхронная работа без заморозки окна
У меня есть мобильное приложение на kivy, работает хорошо. Пока не попробую реализовать в нем асинхронное выполнение парсинга сайта, чтобы главное окно gui kivy не зависало и я мог взаимодействовать с ним во время выполнения долгого процесса. Тогда второй файл парсинг сайта работает некорректно, особенно там, где выполняется ожидание выполнения js. Он то не дожидается выполнения js, то дожидается но с ошибкой где-то в процессе ожидания и вваода результат, в итоге результат не корректен
Пример кода без асинхронного выполнения. Повторяю. Второй файл скрипта работает нормально только в этом режиме (когда в нем вызывается фкнкция через asyncio.run(), а внутри неё new_loop, иначе он не работает нормально с сайтом, на котором выполняетмя js скрипт. (Selenium не предлагать).
Так же я обрабатывал свой вопрос, в chatgpt - не помогло. Перепровал варианты:

стандартные возможности kivymd (from kivymd.utils.asynckivy import start, sleep)
asyncio (и весь main.run() в него и чисто функцию load или только второй скрипт ввызов)
threading / concurrent.futures (чисто через них и совместно с asyncio)
asynckivy (который отделоно устанавливается) тоже не заработал
Ничего не помогло. Приложение удавалось завести асинхронно работать, но вот результат со второго скрипта тогда выполнялся/приходил не правилоно/ый.

Первый скрипт
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.clipboard import Clipboard as Cb
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRoundFlatIconButton
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView
import cheker as checkN

KV = '''
<ContentNavigationDrawer>
    MDList:
        OneLineIconListItem:
            text: "Home"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            on_press:
                root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"
            IconLeftWidget:
                icon: 'home'
                
MDScreen:
    MDBoxLayout:
        id: home
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDTopAppBar:
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            elevation: 4
            title: "OSINT"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
        MDNavigationLayout:
            id: navig
            MDScreenManager:
                id: screen_manager
                MDScreen:
                    id: scr_1
                    name: "scr 1"
                    MDBottomNavigation:
                        id: sc_0
                        selected_color_background: "orange"
                        text_color_active: "lightgrey"
                        MDBottomNavigationItem:
                            id: sc_1
                            name: 'screen 1'
                            text: 'Home'
                            icon: 'home'
                            MDRoundFlatIconButton:
                                id: lst1
                                text: 'Choose option'
                                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.7}
                                on_release: app.menu.open()
                            MDTextField:
                                id: txt
                                hint_text: ''
                                helper_text: ''
                                helper_text_mode: 'persistent'
                                text: ''
                                mode: 'rectangle'
                                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.45}
                                size_hint: 0.28, 0.15
                            MDRoundFlatIconButton:
                                id: startbutton
                                text: 'Start'
                                pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.20}
                                on_release: app.start()
                        MDBottomNavigationItem:
                            id: sc_3
                            name: 'screen 3'
                            text: 'Result'
                            icon: 'text'
                            ScrollView:
                                MDLabel:
                                    id: scroll
                                    markup: True
                                    text: ''
                                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                    text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                                    font_size: '15sp'
                                    multiline: True
                                    text_size: self.width, None
                                    size_hint_y: None
                                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                                    on_touch_down: app.linki(app.bufftext)
                                    on_ref_press: app.webopen(args[1])
            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                radius: (0, 16, 16, 0)
                ContentNavigationDrawer:
                    screen_manager: screen_manager
                    nav_drawer: nav_drawer
'''

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.list_info = ['Number']
        self.dl = Window.width
        self.sh = Window.height

        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)

        menu_items = [
            {
                'id': 'm1',
                'text': f'{i}',
                'viewclass': 'OneLineListItem',
                'on_release': lambda x=f'{i}': self.menu_callback(x),
            } for i in self.list_info
        ]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.screen.ids.lst1,
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=5,
        )

    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        self.screen.ids.lst1.text = text_item
        self.screen.ids.txt.hint_text = text_item
        lst2 = self.screen.ids.sc_1
        self.menu.dismiss()

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.material_style = 'M3'
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        self.title = 'OSINT'
        return self.screen

    def start(self):
        self.screen.ids.sc_0.switch_tab('screen 3')
        self.root.ids.scroll.text = f'Please wait'
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.load(), 1.0)

    def load(self):
        self.res = ''

        opt1 = self.screen.ids.lst1.text
        opt3 = self.screen.ids.txt.text

        if opt1 != 'Choose option':
            if opt1 == 'Number':
                self.res = checkN.parse_num(opt3)
        else:
            self.root.ids.scroll.text = 'Select/enter the correct data.'

        if self.res != '':
            self.root.ids.scroll.text = self.res
        else:
            self.root.ids.scroll.text = 'No results'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()



Второй скрипт (checkN)
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import asyncio
from requests_html import HTMLSession, AsyncHTMLSession

def parse_num(numbers):
    try:
        res1 = europe(numbers)
    except:
        res1 = f'{color.RED}[info]:{color.END}\nError internet/proxy_server/site. Try again.\n'

    try:
        res2 = asyncio.run(all_num(numbers))
    except:
        res2 = f'{color.RED}[whosenumber.info]:{color.END}\nError internet/proxy_server/site. Try again.\n'
        
    try:
        res4 = europe(numbers)
    except:
        res4 = f'{color.RED}[ua.tellows.org]:{color.END}\nError internet/proxy_server/site. Try again.\n'

    res = res1+res2+res4
    return res

async def all_num(numbers):
    uu='https://whosenumber.info'
    headers = {'User-Agent': f'{UserAgent().random}', }
    url = f'{uu}/'
    new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(new_loop)
    session = AsyncHTMLSession()

    response = session.get(f'{url}{numbers}', headers=headers, timeout=60)

    await response.html.arender(sleep=10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, 'html.parser')
    try:
        divF_tag = soup.find('div', attrs={'style':'padding:10px; padding-left:20px;'})
        ttl = ''
        try:
            divS_tag = divF_tag.find('span', attrs={'id':'t_reiting'})
            ttl = divS_tag.get_text()
        except:
            pass
        comm = ''
        try:
            ij = 1
            for p_tag in divF_tag.findAll('div', attrs={'style': 'margin-left:15px;margin-top:10px;color:#6a6a6a; padding-bottom:10px;'}):
                try:
                    pp_tag = p_tag.get_text()
                    pp_tag = pp_tag.replace('<br/>', '')
                    pp_tag = pp_tag.replace('<br>', '')
                    pp_tag = pp_tag.replace('<b/>', '')
                    pp_tag = pp_tag.replace('<b>', '')
                    pp_tag = pp_tag.replace('</b>', '')
                    pp_tag = pp_tag.replace('</br>', '')
                    comm += f'    [{ij}]: {pp_tag}\n'
                    ij+=1
                except:
                    continue
        except:
            pass
        logger.info('all - there is a result')
        resF = (f'{color.RED}[whosenumber.info] - info:{color.END}\n'
                f'{color.BOLD}Rating: {color.END}{ttl}\n{color.BOLD}Comments: {color.END}\n{comm}\n')
    except:
        logger.info('all - result error')
        resF = (f'{color.RED}[whosenumber.info] - info:{color.END}\n'
                f'Error internet/proxy_server/site. Try again.\n')

    res = f'\n{resF}'
    await session.close()
    new_loop.close()
    return res

def europe(numbers):
    uu = 'https://ua.tellows.org'
    headers = {'User-Agent': f'{UserAgent().random}', }
    url = f'{uu}/num/'

    response = requests.get(f'{url}{numbers}', headers=headers, timeout=60)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    try:
        ttl = ""
        comm = ""
        for divF_tag in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'id': 'userratings'}):
            try:
                for divS_tag in divF_tag.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'col-md-4 mt-2'}):
                    try:
                        for h5_tag in divS_tag.findAll('h5'):
                            ttl += f"{color.BOLD}{h5_tag.get_text()}{color.END}\n"
                        for th_tag in divS_tag.findAll('th'):
                            tt = str(th_tag).replace("<th>\n                    ", "")
                            tt = tt.replace("                        ", "")
                            tt = tt.replace('<br/>\n<span class="small">', ": ")
                            tt = tt.replace("</span>\n</th>", "")
                            ttl += f"    {tt}\n"
                    except:
                        continue
            except:
                continue
        for comms_tag in soup.findAll('ol', attrs={'id': 'singlecomments'}):
            try:
                ii = 1
                comm += f"{color.BOLD}Comments: {color.END}\n"
                for comm_tag in comms_tag.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'col comment-body'}):
                    try:
                        for pCom_tag in comm_tag.findAll('p', attrs={'class': 'mb-0'}):
                            comm += f"    [{ii}]{pCom_tag.get_text()}\n"
                            ii += 1
                    except:
                        continue
                    try:
                        jj = 1
                        for dCom_tag in comm_tag.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'ccomment'}):
                            try:
                                comm += f"        [0{jj}]{dCom_tag.get_text()}\n"
                                jj += 1
                            except:
                                continue
                    except:
                        continue
            except:
                continue
        logger.info('Europe - there is a result')
        resF = (f'{color.RED}[ua.tellows.org] - info:{color.END}\n'
                f'{ttl}\n{comm}\n')
    except:
        logger.info('Europe - result error')
        resF = (f'{color.RED}[ua.tellows.org] - info:{color.END}\n'
                f'{color.BOLD}Info: {color.END}Error internet/proxy_server/site. Try again.\n')
    res = f'\n{resF}'
    response.close()
    return res

Прошу протестировать данные мной исходники кода и попробовать запусть асинхронное выполнение kivy, чтобы не замораживало gui окно, но и при это выполнялся нормально (приходил результат с парсинга сайта) второй скрипт, особенно в функции где выпроняется ожидание выпронения js сайта. Для теста номер который нужно ввести в приложении: +37129502847 . Взял с парсингуемого сайта, что точно получить результат.

Посмотрите эту библиотеку: https://github.com/asyncgui/asynckivy

@insolor не сработала что отдельно что уже из kivymd. Она же уже есть в самом kivymd (я писал что пробовал). Я дал полный рабочий исходники примера. Попробуйте внедрить туда асинхрон, чтоб выдавало нормально результат со второго скрипта, особенно с функции all_num, для это можно зайти на сайт, который указан в функции, мкопироватт любой номер от туда. Запустить код и вставить этот номер.

Примеры asynckivy не работают?

ускоряйте работу функций parse_num.

@insolor не работают.

@СергейШ там ускорено на сколько мне нужно. И причём тут это, если мне нужно асинхронное выпронение, чтобы окно kivy не зависело, я на нем параллельно буду выводить таймер
